# Using datepicker to insert date into database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, razorengine

I'm new to asp.net MVC 5.
There is a column in my database which has the type of DateTime, and I want to use datepicker to insert date into it. However, it gave me an error.
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDnzq.png)

my model is like

`[Display(Name = "Found Date")]
 public System.DateTime foundDate { get; set; }`

my view is

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.foundDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.foundDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.foundDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

script

`$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#foundDate").datepicker( {dateformat: 'dd/MM/yyyy'} );
});`

Which date format should be passed to the datetime in the database? How can I change it so that it matches the datepicker's return type?

Any help to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try specifying the datetime format using DataAnnotaions

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

And you can also use conventional HTML5 date time control, just specify the DataType of you model property with the help of data annotation instead of jquery datetime picker like

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
```

hopefully it will help helps

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I declared datatype in the model and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You configured it

```
$("#foundDate").datepicker( {dateformat: 'dd/MM/yyyy'} );
```

but the input is in `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Answer (score 0):

First download the globalize.js , globalize.culture.en-GB.js files and link the these files into your Html page.Finally paste the following code into your script tag.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize.culture.en-GB.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.culture = Globalize.culture("en-GB");
    $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element)
            || Globalize.parseDate(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", "en-GB")
            || Globalize.parseDate(value, "yyyy-mm-dd");
    }
$("#foundDate").datepicker( {dateformat: 'dd/MM/yyyy'} );
});
```